# Does such a finite monoid exist?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, monoid

Does there exist a finite monoid $M$ such that for some $x \in M,$ the following hold?

1. $x$ cancels on both the left and the right:
   $$\frac{ax=bx}{a=b}\qquad \frac{xa=xb}{a=b}$$
2. $x$ has no two-sided inverse:

$$(\forall y \in M)(xy \neq 1 \vee yx \neq 1)$$

I am especially interested in the case where $M$ is commutative.

Comment: The easy example for the infinite case is the natural numbers under addition: all elements are cancellable, but no nonzero element has an inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a monoids person, so I could be way off base here, but here goes:

If $M$ is commutative, then a left- and right-inverse are the same (i.e., if one exists, so does the other. I suppose that there could be 2 or more of each...)

In that case, fix $x$ and look at the map 
$$
h : M \to M : u \mapsto xu.
$$

If that's NOT injective, i.e., if $xu = xv$ for some $u$ and $v$ with $u \ne v$, then you don't have cancellation. So by your hypotheses, $h$ is injective.

Because $M$ is a finite set, that makes $h$ *surjective* as well. So there's a value $u \in M$ with $hu = 1$. (Assuming your monoid HAS a unit, of course.)

Comment: Looks pretty good to me.

Comment: And commutativity is irrelevant: since $x$ is also cancellable on the right, by the same reasoning it has a left inverse. But if an element has both a right and a left inverse, they're equal.